# logstash http output infinite retries

Tags: http, logstash

This is my logstash output config

```
output {
  http {
    url => "http://localhost:8080/test"
    http_method => 'post'
    automatic_retries => 5 
  }
}
```

and it seems that if the response code is 500, it will keep retrying for ever, as if the `automatic_retries` settings is disregarded.

I'm using latest everything

Is this a known bug or am I missing something in the config?

Answer (score 2):

There are two levels of retries in an HTTP output. The [retry_failed](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-http/blob/a8f78ebebc62088ae48f9eb2bc5af097499610bb/lib/logstash/outputs/http.rb#L177) option determines whether the logstash output plugin will retry requests. These are logged at debug level. This is set to true by default, so yes, it will keep retrying. The [automatic_retries](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-mixin-http_client/blob/df096acc0af57f670e60d994b08c3841717f00d3/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/http_client.rb#L108) option determines whether the Manticore HTTP client (which the plugin is a wrapper for) will retry requests. These are not logged.

Answer (score 1):

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-http-output-retries-forever-on-failure/141239 has a discussion on this - it seems very confusing, and the documentation is poor, but it seems that to have it only retry a limited number of times, you need to set retry_failed => false and automatic_retries to the number of retries you want.

I would love there to be some clearer notes to this effect in the plugins documentation (ideally retries would have some kind of backoff)